# ESP32 NodeMCU-32S ai thinker UART does not work

Tags: uart, esp32

i need to connect my ESP32 NodeMCU-32S ai thinker to other sensor via UART, to debug my UART code i connected ESP32 UART TX pin to ESP32 RX pin.
when TX is short to RX the ESP32 Arduino IDE faield to connect but when i disconnect TX from RX Arduino IDE is connecting to the ESP32 board.
this happen even when my code is only loop and setup.

RX - GPI03
TX - GPI01

do you have any suggestions how to solve the problem

Comment: the USB chip is connected to the same UART

Comment: no the USB is connected to other sensor

Comment: add pin numbers to question. what sensor is connected to USB?

Comment: no for debuging purpose the USB is connected to the compuiter and the RX is connected  to TX

Comment: Why are you shorting RX and TX? To create a loopback setup? If so, try it with a resistor instead of a short. I've made similar experience with FTDI USB-to-serial converter.

Comment: Or even better: instead of a physical connection, try a software solution that reads a byte from UART and immediately sends it again.

Comment: the USB converter chip is on board connected to UART on io 1 and io 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RX and TX are used for the onboard USB controller (C02102) and in order to use UART one need to use P16 and P17 (GPIO16 and GPIO17)